# Prove the left multiplication $L_A$ operator in $\mathcal{B}(\ell_2)$ is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Can someone assist me in showing that this operator is continuous as a map in the weak operator topology? I tried to do this with nets, but got stuck trying to "move" the operation inside the inner product.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean: for $A\in B(\ell_2)$ fixed, prove that $L_A:T\longmapsto AT$ is continuous from $B(\ell^2)$ to itself, equipped with the wot on both sides? If so, this boils down to observing that $\langle AT_ix,y \rangle =\langle T_ix,A^*y\rangle$.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Can you explain what you mean by A*? I don't think I have encountered that notation before.

Comment: That's the adjoint of the operator $A$, without which it would be cumbersome to answer such a question. I strongly suggest that you learn about the adjoint before even bothering considering the weak operator topology...[See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint).

Comment: Thanks! I am familiar with the Riesz representation theorem so using that to prove that the adjoint exists made this quite easy :)

Answer (score 1):

This result can be easily generalised for an arbitrary normed space $X$.

The weak operator topology $wo$ on $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is generated by the family of seminorms 
$$
\{\Vert\cdot\Vert_{x,f}:\mathcal{B}(X)\to\mathbb{R_+}:T\mapsto |f(T(x))|:x\in X,\;y\in X^*\}
$$
Let $(T_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda)\subset\mathcal{B}(X)$ be an arbitrary net that $wo$-converges to $T\in\mathcal{B}(X)$, then for all $x\in X$ and $f\in X^*$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\Vert L_A(T_i)-L_A(T)\Vert_{x,f}
&=\lim\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda}|f((AT_\lambda-AT)(x))|\\
&=\lim\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda}|(A^*(f))((T_\lambda-T)(x))|\\
&=\lim\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\Vert T_\lambda-T\Vert_{x,A^*f}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Hence the net $(L_A(T_\lambda):\lambda\in\Lambda)$ $wo$-converges to $L_A(T)$. Since $(T_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda)$ is arbitrary, then $L_A$ $wo$-$wo$-continuous on $\mathcal{B}(X)$.